# iOS app rejected - Guideline 5.1.2 - Legal - Privacy - Data Use and Sharing. "create a unique identifier for the user's device"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods, app-store

"We found in our review that your app collects user and device information to create a unique identifier for the user's device. Apps that fingerprint the user's device in this way are in violation of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement and are not appropriate for the App Store.
Specifically, your app uses algorithmically converted device and usage data to create unique identifier in order track the user. The device information collected by your app may include some of the following: defaultManager, NSLocaleCollationIdentifier, NSLocaleQuotationBeginDelimiterKey, NSLocaleCurrencySymbol, and NSLocaleExemplarCharacterSet."

I don't know how to resolve this issue. I store "UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString" and "UUID().uuidString" in UserDefaults and Keychain, then send them to server.

parts of Podfile

```
pod 'AppAuth', '1.2.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '7.5.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '7.5.0'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '7.5.0'
pod 'Firebase/Performance', '7.5.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '7.5.0'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '7.5.0'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '9.0.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '9.0.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '9.0.0'
# Ads
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.69.0'
pod 'FBAudienceNetwork', '6.2.1'
pod 'InMobiSDK/Core', '9.1.1'
pod 'mopub-ios-sdk', '5.15.0'
pod 'Verizon-Ads-StandardEdition', '1.8.1'
# Ads Medation
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook', '6.2.1.0'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationInMobi', '9.1.1.0'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationMoPub', '5.15.0.0'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationVerizonMedia', '1.8.1.0'
pod 'AppBoxoSDK', '1.3.39'
pod 'SAMKeychain'
```

**Update:**

---

@dfd Thanks, bro. You saved me a lot of time. I changed the App Privacy and privacy policy on appstoreconnect, then the review passed.

---

Comment: Two thoughts. First, the rejection appears to be fairly specific, and may give you what you need to change. Second, what is your privacy policy? I see Google Mobile Ads along with Verizon Mobile Ads. (More, but those two jumped out at me.) Months ago Apple started asking for more details about your privacy policy. This is up to you to provide. Maybe you don't *mean* or *intend* to track users, but your third party SDKs do. And Apple will reject your submissions - including updates - if they detect false policies.

Comment: I don’t know how you’ll track that down to resolve the issue, but I’m sure it’s one or multiple of those third-parties, not your use of identifiers. That’s a sketchy and long list of libraries you’re including in your app and you don’t know what data they’re collecting to track your users.

Comment: @dfd Thanks, bro. You saved me a lot of time. I changed the App Privacy and privacy policy on appstoreconnect, then the review passed.

Comment: @wangabstract we saw the similar rejection issue. Out of curiosity, could you share how you changed the App Privacy and privacy policy?

Comment: @MakotoTaguchi hi, remove App Privacy > Identifier > User Identifier > Thirdparty Ads and Developer Ads selection, remove App Privacy > Identifier > Device Identifier > Thirdparty Ads  and Developer Ads selection, and make privacy policy available.

Comment: @wangabstract Do you mean uncheck these options? 这两个选项不勾选就好了吗？

Comment: @mengxiangjian  是的，另外我还是删除了UUID().uuidString的引用，但是这个应该不影响什么

Answer (score 0):

It's cause of Adjust SDK. You can refer to this [link](https://blog.embrace.io/apple-app-rejections/).

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another hint of how to solve this issue.

#### Long Story Short

I found out that when I imported `Branch` with `CocoaPods`, `AdSupport` was being dynamically linked to the App for some reason. Switching to `Swift Package Manager` solved my issue.

I also updated my Privacy Settings as suggested above and I made sure I answered *NO* to the second section of each section (*NO* to tracking).

#### Full Disclosure

IDFA can be used as long as you [ask permission to the user](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency) . This doesn't prevent a 3rd party from trying to access this identifier (the system will just return 0s). See for instance how [Branch](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking-attribution/issues/1052) handles it, they check at runtime for `AdSupport` framework.

From my understanding, if they detect this framework is linked (you don't necessarily see it in your project's `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`) they'll reject your App.

In my case, I found out that when I imported `Branch` with `CocoaPods`, `AdSupport` was being linked for some reason. Switching to `Swift Package Manager` solved my issue. You can check it by using this snippet:

```swift
// DO NOT IMPORT AdSupport

if NSClassFromString("ASIdentifierManager") != nil {
  print("AdSupport is linked somehow")
}
```

I also reviewed my Privacy Settings, but this is very particular for every App. In every section, I updated the checkboxes as best as I could and after clicking *Next* I made sure the second question (referring to tracking) was answered as *NO*.

Finally, for *User ID* and *Device ID* sections, I made sure that *Third-Party Advertising* and *Developer’s Advertising or Marketing* were unchecked.